# Detect Default proxy setting .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, http-proxy

I'm trying to get default proxy setting and implementing via httpclient.

```
           IWebProxy webProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
            if(webProxy.GetProxy(new 
              System.Uri(url)).AbsoluteUri != null))
```

if its not, then try to set via manaully. I'm getting exception Not supported plateform. what is best way to detect proxy setting of user before making any API call.